# Can't download Steam on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: steam

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and when I try to download Steam, the Ubuntu software center pops up and I receive this message.

```
Can't download Steam on Ubuntu "dependency is not sastifactible: curl"
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: You may just need to install `curl`. Press ctrl+alt+t, type `sudo apt-get install curl`.

Answer (score 0):

open a terminal and run "sudo apt-get install curl" then "sudo apt-get install -f" then try installing. If it gives another dependency then replace curl in the first command with the name of the new dependency